# How to document inline protocol using appledoc

Tags: protocols, appledoc

I have defined an Objective-C @class that defines a @protocol inline in the header before the @interface.

I can't get appledoc to generate the docs for the protocol. Is it possible inline or does the protocol need to be a separate file?

Answer (score 0):

The protocol doesn't need to be defined in a separate header file.
I'm using it myself in a construction like this (same header file):

MyClass.h

```
/** The `MyClassDelegate` will notify the controller about anything that happens inside `MyClass`
 */
@protocol MyClassDelegate <NSObject>
//Protocol definition
@end


/** This class has some cool methods and properties
 */
@interface MyClass : NSObject
//Class definition
@end
```